# PT10 & Soundminer V4.3 Pro

Tags: pro-tools, soundminer, workflow

Hi guys,

Has anyone tried running sm v4.3 pro with PT 10?

Any issues?

Many thanks

Rada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm working with PT10 (on OsX 10.6.8) and SMpro 4.3: it works, but SM doesn't auto-detect the PT session you're working on, so you just have to manually set it. Furthermore, the new PT functions (like interleaved audiofiles) aren't supported in SM: it just means that you cannot send an interleaved file to PT (an annoying popup appears).

However, all the other functions in SM behave like they always did. And I'm really really happy with the new Pro Tools release!

Davide

Comment: v.4.3.6 was released last week to deal with some bugs that were popping up in v.4.3.3. you may want to check that out. don't know if it fixes your issues, as we haven't upgraded to PT10 yet.

Comment: Already have 4.3.6. ☺ BTW I'm still on 10.6.8. I'm putting the final touches to a dialogue edit, so I did't do any deep test with it. Jumping to PT10 when I was working on this project was already a great jump (but I had a backup system!). Well worth, PT10 is MUCH more responsive than 9 (on my native system) and AS handles and clip gain are just great

Answer (score 1):

Doing it, seems to be working just fine, including session detection here.
Using 4.3 v3
FWIW

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just detecting the old session that maybe you have in the same folder? 